# What does "kicking-ass" mean in job descriptions?

Tags: job-search, new-job

I'm graduating soon and looking for jobs as a software engineer/developer. I often read the following phrase in the requirements "you have a history in kicking-ass", so what the hell does that even meaaaan!!!?

Examples:

http://berlinstartupjobs.com/companies/gigflip/

http://berlinstartupjobs.com/engineering/java-frontend-mobile-developer-mf-visual-meta-gmbh-2/

search for "ass"

Comment: Can't say for sure until I read the full ad. I once worked for a CEO who did kick employee ass but achieved absolutely nothing except driving his firm into the ground.

Comment: there was also a movie once about vigilantes who fought crime on the street, maybe the companies you are looking at have monetised that concept?

Comment: this depends on [company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2694)

Comment: "Often"? I'm surprised if so. I would presume they just mean it in the idiomatic sense of exceeding expectations and beating the competition.

Comment: That someone is the next Jon Skeet.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan added examples

Comment: @gnat added examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original: "We are in search for a kick-ass executive assistant with 1+ years of relevant experience."

Translation: "We are in search for a very effective executive assistant with 1+ years of relevant experience."

Original: "Analytical mindset with a kick-ass 'getting things done' mentality"

Translation: "Analytical mindset with a hard core “get it done” mentality", as in "finish it and I don't care who gets hurt or whose pet gets run over while you're doing it"

1. @nvoigt has it down - the addition of "kick ass" when used as an adjective makes for nice action theater if you like action movies but if you look at it without passion, it's just feel good crap. In other words, think "junk food for the mind" But then, most job ads are junk food for the mind anyway :)
2. Having said that, an established company is unlikely to use the phrase "kick ass" - it's a company-cultural thing, it's a generational thing and it tells you that twentyish to thirtyish hipsters are running the company that's doing the hiring.
3. "kick ass" is an American expression and the startups that advertise are German, so it's possible that it's a nice case of cultural exchange between American troops stationed in Germany and the German host population.

Comment: +1 For _an established company is unlikely to use the phrase "kick ass"_.

Answer (score 1):

It does not mean anything. The ad would read the same if you just left out that phrase.

It's a filler word that was put in to somehow sound "cool" or "hipster" or however the startup music scene thinks of itself.